# How to reference a matrix key uniformly from a build matrix that has an include option?

Tags: github-actions

In the below workflow, I am trying to set the environment variable `PERL_NAME`, but `${{ matrix.perl }}` is empty for `macos-latest`, whereas I would like it to be `34`:

```
name: linux-build-dist
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build-perls:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        perl: [34, 32, 30, 28, 26]
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        include:
          - os: macos-latest
          - perl: 34
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install perl
        env:
          PERL_NAME: perl-5.${{ matrix.perl }}.0
        run: |
          ./.github/scripts/install_perl.sh
```

I think I would need to instead use something like `${{ matrix.include.perl }}` ? But then this would not work for `ubuntu-latest` since it does not use the `include` option. How can I get the correct perl version for both `ubuntu-latest` and `macos-latest` ?

Answer (score 1):

A dirty way would be to have `if` conditions like below,

```
name: linux-build-dist
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build-perls:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        perl: [34, 32, 30, 28, 26]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install perl Ubuntu
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
        env:
          PERL_NAME: perl-5.${{ matrix.perl }}.0
        run: |
          ./.github/scripts/install_perl.sh

      - name: install perl Mac
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'macos-latest' && matrix.perl == '34' }}
        env:
          PERL_NAME: perl-5.${{ matrix.perl }}.0
        run: |
          ./.github/scripts/install_perl.sh
```